# Calculation of hypochlorite concentration from active chlorine

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry

So in the lab we got sodium hypochlorite solution. The concentration is in active chlorine (13%) on the label. How do I calculate it to concentration of hypochlorite? I need certain amount of hypochlorite (0,868g roughly) for the reaction I am trying to do and because it is not going as described in the article as they were using 5% hypochlorite solution I am checking for possible miscalculations on my part.

Thank you for the help and answers in advance

Answer (score 0):

The active chlorine, in %, is the mass-percentage of $\ce{Cl2}$
dissolved in the solution, without taking into account the fact that this $\ce{Cl2}$ may be at least partially transformed into $\ce{ClO-}$ or $\ce{HClO}$, according to one of the two equations depending upon the pH value :   $$\ce{Cl2 + 2 OH^- -> ClO^- + Cl- + H2O}$$ $$\ce{Cl2 + H2O -> HClO + Cl- + H+}$$

One liter solution with $13$% active chlorine has been made with $130$ g $\ce{Cl2}$ being dissolved into enough $\ce{NaOH}$ solution. And $130$ g $\ce{Cl2}$ is $\frac{130 g}{71 g/mol} = 1.83$ mol $\ce{Cl2}$. This solution has a concentration [$\ce{ClO^-}] = 1.83$ M.

The origin of the word "active" is coming from the fact that, if such a solution is acidified with some strong acid, the previous equations will be reversed, and $1$ L solution with $13$% active chlorine will liberate $130$ g chlorine $\ce{Cl2}$.

Pleas take notice that sodium hypochlorite cannot be obtained easily as a dry substance by evaporating its solution. If such a solution is evaporated by heating it, $\ce{NaClO}$ will disproportionate according to $$\ce{3 ClO^- -> ClO3^- + 2 Cl^- }$$

Comment: From Wikipedia: "The anhydrous compound is unstable and may decompose explosively. It can be crystallized as a pentahydrate NaOCl·5H2O, a pale greenish-yellow solid which is not explosive and is stable if kept refrigerated."    I suppose that if you evaporate a solution of sodium hypochlorite, you might get the pentahydrate as a solid. I did this some years ago; it didn't explode till I added some sulfuric acid.

Comment: @James Gaidis. Heating a solution of $\ce{NaClO}$ is the industrial way of synthesizing sodium chlorate. So if you want to get $\ce{NaClO}$ crystals, you must evaporate it at low temperature, not far from $\pu{0°C}$. And this is not easy to do.

Comment: @JamesGaidis “it didn't explode till I added some sulfuric acid.” ;-)